# Why does Laravel middleware get executed multiple times?

Tags: laravel, logging, laravel-middleware

I am trying to add a very simple visitor logging to my Laravel site, just by adding a new middleware, with a log line, but I am getting two log entries on each request?

The middleware is very straight forward:

```php
class LogVisitor
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        Log::channel('access')->info($request->ip() .';' . $request->url());

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I have even tried to move the logging line to the terminate method:

```php
class LogVisitor
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function terminate(Request $request, $response)
    {
        Log::channel('access')->info($request->ip() .';' . $request->url());
    }
}
```

but it makes no different...
I have even tried to add a variable to the $request variable, and check if it is set, but it looks like the $request variable is also reset on each execution.

It looks like the whole thing is being executed twice, but if I try to make a var_dump inside, it only shows once..

I was expecting it to run only once?
Does anyone have a good idea how to make sure it only moakes one entry pr request?

Comment: The middleware is being executed on each request, it is part of the request lifecycle. So now it depends on what you need to do. But if you group multiple routes and apply the middleware on it, the middleware will run on each request in the group. 

Share your use-case, maybe you are looking for something else rather then a middleware.

Comment: @nakov I want it to create a log entry every time someone visits a page. It is done by grouping all the routes I want to be logged, and applying the middleware to this group.
As for test, I have also tried to add the middleware to the web-group, just to see if it had something to do with the grouping, but with the same result.

Comment: Sorry my friend I misread your question. Now I see what your real question is. Can you please tell me where did you registered your custom middleware? Because I just tried the first middleware with logging in the `handle` method and I got only one log message.

Comment: @nakov its fine, it is already solved :) as N69S said, it was because Google Chrome is making a pre-fligt request (option request) before it makes a GET request, and therefore it makes two requests.
All i had to do was to filter out the option request.

To answer your question, then I am applying my middleware directly in the /routes/web.php file, by making a group with this middleware

Comment: I saw his answer and I am glad it works. But I am testing on Chrome as well, and I never had to wrap any logic within a condition to check which method type is used. I use it in the `web.php` and I registered the middleware in the `Kernel.php` in a `$routeMiddleware` array.

Comment: Yes, I think I was too quick on the trigger. There is still an issue. Both requests being logged, is GET requests, Not OPTION

Comment: So I tested on a public route with just this middleware it works great, logs only once. Try that, if you apply other middlewares on that route try changing the order. Or share some more code so I can try to help more, as I cannot reproduce the same behavior atm.

Comment: Im starting to think this is not a code issue. I just tested using firefox, internet explorer, an API module.. all of them only fires one entry.. it is ONLY Chrome firing two

Comment: As I said I tested in Chrome as well, and it is okay. Try Chrome in incognito tab, without any plugins. It can be 100 different things, but as you are not sharing any other details, I don't think I can be of any help :)

Comment: I found it.. OMG this is embarrasing.. I reinstalled Chrome, then it fires only one.. Then I logged in, and it started to sync my plugins.. then it makes two.. I found out it was one of my chrome modules making that extra request for some wierd reason! But now it is solved :)

Comment: haha, yes, thank you very much for your time and effort @nakov, I am sorry i wasted your time with something as stupid as this

Answer (score 3):

I think you are facing the `OPTION` pre-flight request from browsers.

When you launch a request on another domain other than the one you are in, the browser launchs an `OPTION` request that your middleware might have caught.

if the `OPTION` request return 200, the browser then runs the `Get/Post/..` request you needed.

Try this

```
class LogVisitor
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']!='OPTIONS') {
            Log::channel('access')->info($request->ip() .';' . $request->url());
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly! It just hit me, you just got to write it first haha.. I just tested using internet explorer, and it only generates one entry, because it doesnt (like chrome) start with a pre-flight...
But thank you for your answer hehe

Comment: Hmmm, something wierd is still going on @N69S. I am very sure you are right, but it is still triggered twice, in Chrome. When I try to log the request method, they are both requested using GET, and thats why it is not filtered out with the isMethod('option')

Comment: @DennisNielsen make a cors middleware that triggers first and responds to `OPTION` call before it reach your log middleware or try detecting the `OPTION` request with `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='OPTIONS') {`

Comment: In addition to OPTIONS request, perhaps you can also check if it is an AJAX request by using `$request->ajax()` because there can also be ajax requests in your page.

Comment: @Mycodingproject what does the request being an XHR has to do with any of this ?

Comment: I thought if there is also an ajax request going on, perhaps it is also hitting to the Middleware. I haven't tried it but it was just an idea.